# Changes to django's urls.py not reflected online

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I'm running a Django application using NGINX and UWSGI.

My URLpatterns used to be this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index),
    url(r'^binaryQuestionApp/',include('binaryQuestionApp.urls')),
    url(r'^pointlocations/',include('pointlocations.urls')),
    url(r'^attributesFromPointsApp/',include('attributesFromPointsApp.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Yet, I wish to change it to this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index),
    url(r'^collections/',views.collections),                  ## new line ##
    url(r'^binaryQuestionApp/',include('binaryQuestionApp.urls')),
    url(r'^pointlocations/',include('pointlocations.urls')),
    url(r'^attributesFromPointsApp/',include('attributesFromPointsApp.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Yet, after pushing this to my server (and the .py file does change on the server) I consistently get Django's 404 page:

```
Using the URLconf defined in data_collection_project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^$
^binaryQuestionApp/
^pointlocations/
^attributesFromPointsApp/
^admin/
^media\/(?P<path>.*)$
The current URL, randomurltoget404page, didn't match any of these.
```

If I change something else, for the sake of testing, I can get the change to work. For example, I can make changes to the .html file that `url(r'^$', views.index),` eventually points to, which is update on my site.

How do I get Django to update the URLpatterns? Related questions tell me to restart uwsgi or nginx, which I've tried using `sudo service uwsgi restart` to no avail.

Comment: delete the `urls.pyc` maybe it loads it from cache?

Comment: You're trying some random url which is not defined in your url conf?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye I did, that will give the 404 page. In fact, in the example I tried navigating to `mywebsite/randomurltoget404page`

Comment: @MitchellvanZuylen So I don't understand the problem. An undefined url should give a 404.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye he wants to access `/collections/` but for the sake of testing he typed something to show you, that `data_collection_projects.urls` isn't even showing `collections` as an option.

Comment: @user1I tried to delete the `urls.pyc` but nothing changes.

Comment: @MitchellvanZuylen after deletion you did restart uwsgi again?

Comment: After changes to code, you need to at least reload the uwsgi service.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you correctly mentioned in your question, you need to reload/restart your uWSGI service after you've changed code.

If this does not work the service is loading cached data and does not reload your changes. To clean cached data delete all or the corresponding `*.pyc` file and restart the service again.

In your case delete `urls.pyc` and then restart with `sudo service uwsgi restart`

Comment: I run my uwsgi from a virtualenv. Would it work the same if I use `sudo service /home/virtualenv/virtualfolder/uwsgi restart`?

Comment: in case of gunicorn, do the same, delete the *.pyc file, restart gunicorn.